# Xodus warning about FileDataWriter

Tags: xodus

When I start-up my application, xodus gives out a warning:

```
WARN jetbrains.exodus.io.FileDataWriter - Can't open directory channel. Log directory fsync won't be performed.
```

Could someone give me advice about what this means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning should appear only when running applications under Windows. Under Windows, a channel for the directory, where the database exists, can't be opened. Thus, directory structure cannot be fsynced using Java NIO API. Such OS  limitation can probably affect transaction durability, but still there is no known bug related to it. You can ignore the warning.

Comment: An issue has been reported to JetBrains: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/XD-841